# Space Complexity of a Recursive Code

Tags: algorithm, recursion, analysis

Consider the following Java method:

```
   public static void f(int n) {
    if (n<=1) { 
       System.out.print(n) ; 
       return; 
   }else {
       f(n/2) ;
       System.out.print(n);
       f(n/2);
    }
 } // end of method
```

Question 3. Let S(n) denote the space complexity of f(n). Which of the
following statements is correct?

- A: S(n) = (2n)
- B: S(n) = (n)
- C: S(n) = (log n) <- Correct answer, anyone know why?
- D: none of the above

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to post online exams and ask people to take those exams. Stack Overflow is a place to ask programming related Q&A sites. So if you ever expect to get some help on this question you will have to provide your analysis so far and illustrate the efforts you have put into solving it explaining any possible difficulties you might have encountered during this process.

Comment: thanks for your useless comment, Its not like I was trying to get an answer out... i knew the answer. Sometimes you just dont know where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever the function calls itself recursively all local variables remain on the stack and a new set of them are pushed to the stack for the new call.
This means that you care how many calls are there at most, in other words what is the maximum depth of the recursion.

It's clear that it's log n, because the successive argumetns are n, n/2, n/4, ..., 1.
There is a constant number of local variables, namely 1 (for which space is needed on the stack) therefore the overall space complexity is O(log n).